# JavaFX: Call function on controller when corresponding stage is closed

Tags: javafx

Is there a way to trigger a function in a controller, when the stage containing the view connected to the controller is closed? Let’s say I want to call a “cleanup” function (e.g. save changes) on every controller in my stage, when the window is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you put the content of the FXML file into a stage (via a scene) externally to the FXML and controller. So you should add code where you actually have access to the stage to do this. You can define a method in your controller class to invoke when you need to do the "cleanup":

```
public class Controller {

    // injected fields, etc...

    public void initialize() {
        // initialization code...
    }

    // event handlers, etc...

    public void shutdown() {
        // cleanup code here...
    }
}
```

Now when you load the FXML and display its content in a window, you can register a handler with the stage that invokes the controller's shutdown method:

```
Stage stage = ... ;

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/fxml/file"));
Parent root = loader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);

// cleanup controller resources when window closes:
Controller controller = loader.getController();
stage.setOnHidden(e -> controller.shutdown());

stage.show();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick. I also added some code to call the “shutdown” methods of the nested controllers included in the main controller as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Window.setOnHidden`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#setOnHidden-javafx.event.EventHandler-)